# Clang: Where -Wall option is defined?

Tags: c, macos, gcc, makefile, clang

I'm reading [Learn C The Hard Way book](https://learncodethehardway.org/c/), exercise 2.
There is a Makefile in the exercise like this ([reference to GitHub repo](https://github.com/zedshaw/learn-c-the-hard-way-lectures/blob/master/ex2/Makefile)):

```
CFLAGS=-Wall -g

all: ex1

clean:
    rm -f ex1
```

I checked `man cc` to find `-Wall` option definition, but I couldn't find it ([link to clang documentation](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/CommandGuide/clang.html)). But, I found `-Wall` option in [gcc documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-6.2.0/gcc/Warning-Options.html#Warning-Options).

- Q1. Why can I pass `-Wall` option to clang, even though it is not defined in clang?
- Q2. What is the relationship between clang and gcc here?

---

My development environment: macOS Sierra 10.12.1, Xcode 8.1 is installed.

Comment: Generally, if GCC supports the option, so does `clang`.  `clang` has some options (`-Weverything`, for example) that GCC does not.  Good luck getting code past `-Weverything`; it isn't impossible, but some of the warnings are really not very helpful in general (one warns about impeccable code that tests standard-defined macros, for example; another analyzes the text of comments(!) and decides whether that is OK — I use `-Wno-padded -Wno-vla -Wno-reserved-id-macro -Wno-documentation-unknown-command` with `-Weverything`).

Comment: @nos, on that page that you linked to, under 'Options to Control Error and Warning Messages' there is a link to the diagnostics reference, which details all of the possible flags, including `-Wall`.

Comment: @Keita, if I provided the documentation that you were looking for, feel free to mark the answer as the accepted solution so others know this question has a solution that worked for the asker.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`-Wall` is defined in Clang. For reference for their diagnostic messages (including `-Wall`), see http://clang.llvm.org/docs/DiagnosticsReference.html.

> [-Wall](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/DiagnosticsReference.html#id21)
>
> Some of the diagnostics controlled by this flag are enabled by
>   default.
>
> Controls [-Wmost](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/DiagnosticsReference.html#wmost), [-Wparentheses](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/DiagnosticsReference.html#wparentheses), [-Wswitch](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/DiagnosticsReference.html#wswitch), [-Wswitch-bool](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/DiagnosticsReference.html#wswitch-bool).

You can click the other flags to dig deeper into all the various options that are selected.

I have found Clang's documentation to be complete for all of the things that I have used it for, although I certainly haven't come close to exhausting the capabilities of Clang.

`gcc` and `cc` have more in common than where they differ, and the LLVM project does a pretty objective comparison here: http://clang.llvm.org/comparison.html.

Comment: Thanks you for the answer and the direct link to the Diagnostic flags page. That's what I wanted to check!

Answer (score 1):

clang is part of the [LLVM](http://llvm.org/) project.  It is completely separate from GCC (which is part of the [GNU](http://www.gnu.org/) project); they share no code.  However, it has a design goal of being *compatible* with GCC; it implements nearly all the same command-line options, and nearly all the same extensions to C and C++.

clang's documentation is very incomplete compared to gcc's.  Not finding any mention of `-Wall` in clang's documentation means only that they haven't gotten around to finishing that part of the documentation yet.

Comment: I hope this doesn't sound needlessly inflammatory (not my intent), but I downvoted because you didn't give the link for the documentation for the -Wfoo options which is available from Google, or from a link on the user manual for Clang. I think that you should've made an effort to find that before claiming that "clang's documentation is very incomplete compared to gcc's. Not finding any mention of -Wall in clang's documentation means only that they haven't gotten around to finishing that part of the documentation yet."

Comment: @GregSchmit I was speaking of the manuals as a whole, and what I said about them is factually true and should be self-evident to anyone who has read both. I admit to being too lazy to edit in some links demonstrating the point, and if you want to downvote me for that that's your prerogative.

Comment: If you wanted to merely claim that the documentation isn't great or as complete as `gcc`'s, that's fine, although it would be a red herring (having almost nothing to do with the question). I was specifically talking about not finding mention of `-Wall` and supposing that they just haven't gotten around to finishing that part of the documentation. If you had read both of the documentations (as you suggest you have), then knowing that the compiler warning switches are all defined would be known to you.

Comment: @zwol Thank you for answering and explaining LLVM's Clang vs GNU's GCC, which I was not clear about!